# Aplicación Android 7 cierra después de tomar foto

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema ya que tengo una aplicación que la modifique para funcionar en android 7 para tomar fotos, el código del intent para tomar foto en mi activitiy es el siguiente:

```
   private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                //mCapturedImageURI = Uri.parse(createImageFile().getPath());
                mCapturedImageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        createImageFile());
            }
            else {
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            UErrores.mostrarError(e, MainActivity.this);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //temp sd card file
        takePictureIntent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_IMAGE_FOR_ANDROID_5);
        } else
        {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_IMAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Al momento de tomar varias fotos la aplicación se cierra o se reinicia (el momento es random) pero esto pasa al probarlo en un teléfono HTC, ademas lo probé en otro teléfono de marca genérica BLECK con android 7 y no pasa esto. Ojala puedan orientarme en que es lo que puede estar pasando.

Saludos.

UPDATE:
Debo mencionar que la acción de tomar foto se realiza en un WebView, lamentablemente al momento de reiniciar la aplicación no logro capturar el log porque se reinicia junto con la aplicación, solo el log que se genera después de reiniciar:

```
11-21 09:40:57.278 22554-22554/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-21 09:40:57.279 22554-22554/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:22554
11-21 09:40:57.670 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.capture.advan.capture-2/lib/arm64
11-21 09:40:57.737 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
11-21 09:40:57.738 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/MultiDex: install
11-21 09:40:57.738 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
11-21 09:40:57.768 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-21 09:40:58.208 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture E/SincronizaService: initializeLocationManager
11-21 09:40:58.294 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture E/SincronizaService: onCreate
11-21 09:40:58.550 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-21 09:40:58.672 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 62.0.3202.84 (code 320208452)
11-21 09:40:58.792 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 13 ms (timestamps 1004-1017)
11-21 09:40:58.815 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(46)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-21 09:40:58.816 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "62.0.3202.84", actual native library version number "62.0.3202.84"
11-21 09:40:58.909 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
11-21 09:40:58.954 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : b6da14b, I47548ba842
                                                               Build Date                       : 12/07/16
                                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                               Local Branch                     : 
                                                               Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.3.6_RB1.07.00.00.255.023
                                                               Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                               Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.android.webview.chromium.eb>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/webkit/RenderProcessGoneDetail;
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:635)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:571)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:554)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:541)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:717)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:785)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:861)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
11-21 09:40:59.044 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.capture.advan.capture.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:540)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6673)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1136)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2678)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2786)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1501)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:173)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6459)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:938)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:828)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at com.android.webview.chromium.Ap com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.G(android.webkit.WebView, android.content.Context) (WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:323)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(java.util.Map, boolean) (WebViewChromium.java:42)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int, java.util.Map, boolean) (WebView.java:635)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int) (WebView.java:571)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) (WebView.java:554)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.webkit.WebView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (WebView.java:541)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:645)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:717)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:785)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:727)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:858)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:861)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:821)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.capture.advan.capture.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:540)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6673)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1136)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2678)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2786)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1501)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:173)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6459)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:938)
11-21 09:40:59.045 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:828)
11-21 09:40:59.284 22554-22669/com.capture.advan.capture D/AudioManager: isHeadsetPlugged = false
11-21 09:40:59.287 22554-22669/com.capture.advan.capture W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
11-21 09:40:59.353 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-21 09:40:59.394 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/ac3
11-21 09:40:59.396 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/eac3
11-21 09:40:59.397 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture W/AudioCapabilities: Unsupported mime audio/eac3-joc
11-21 09:40:59.399 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
11-21 09:40:59.469 22554-22715/com.capture.advan.capture I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
11-21 09:40:59.592 22554-22722/com.capture.advan.capture W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/com.capture.advan.capture/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
11-21 09:40:59.729 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "script0", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (12)
11-21 09:40:59.876 22554-22561/com.capture.advan.capture W/art: Suspending all threads took: 17.761ms
11-21 09:40:59.928 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (12)
11-21 09:40:59.928 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(27)] "script00", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (27)
11-21 09:41:00.513 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(31)] "script1", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (31)
11-21 09:41:00.648 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "ready1", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (33)
11-21 09:41:00.649 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "i=1", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (33)
11-21 09:41:00.649 22554-22554/com.capture.advan.capture I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "ready3", source: file:///storage/emulated/0/formularios/2329.html (33)
```

UPDATE 2: Agrego mi archivo build_grandle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply from: 'strip_play_services.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.capture.advan.capture"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.0'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2') with module('commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2')
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes poner el log para ver el error?

Comment: ¿Aparece algún texto en el log? Algo como "segmentation fault" o "unknown exception"

Comment: Lamentablemente no logro capturar log cuando crashea porque se reinicia junto con la aplicación solo logro capturar el log que arroja después de que reinicia la aplicación

Comment: Tu aplicacion se llama `com.capture.advan.capture`?

Comment: si así se llama, es el nombre del paquete..

Comment: @MIKI90 agrega tu archivo build.gradle por favor!

Comment: Eh añadido el archivo build Grandle

Answer (score 0):

Un poco raro el error, especificamente se registra en el LogCat:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.webkit.RenderProcessGoneDetail" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/lib/arm64,
>   /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64,
>   /vendor/lib64]]

Comentas que en ocasiones sucede y otras no, te recomiendo asegures no tienes habilitado `Instant Run`, esto para evitar que solo las partes actualizadas de tu proyecto sean reemplazadas en el dispositivo:

Ve a `File` > `Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Instant Run` , Aquí elimina la selección de esta opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya estuve probando y sigue pasando con los cambios que comentas.